# HTML Email Link Item is blank when outputting to PDF

Tags: html, email, pdf-generation

I want the ability to click on a HTML item that automatically opens up an email with the email address dynamically enter into the email to address box. I've got this to work in Cognos but when I output it to PDF the item is blank i.e. I can't click on anything to lanch the email. Here's the text in the first HTML report expression: `'<a href= "mailto:email address">'` and in the second: `'email address</a>'` I can't understand why the HTML link isn't working properly. Any ideas? This is for Cognos Version 9.5

Answer (score 0):

What's your cognos server version, this error looks like the one you're getting:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM66347

Comment: I'm actually not getting any error message, it just disappears on the PDF. My Cognos versionis 9.5